# Bloch's Builder Pattern with Spring

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, constructor, javabeans

I have numerous constructors inside one of my Classes so I thought it would be a good idea to to implement Bloch's "Builder Pattern" (see http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2) for one of the Classes (Spring Project).

It's quite possible, I have missed something as I am getting an "IllegalArgumentException" when running a Test Case against the Class. Does Spring allow for this type of stuff or shall I just opt for the conventional multiple constructor approach?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No serializer found for class com.AllTweets$Builder and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: com.AllTweets["builder"])
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:2502)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:2482)
at org.springframework.data.redis.hash.JacksonHashMapper.toHash(JacksonHashMapper.java:52)
at org.springframework.data.redis.hash.DecoratingStringHashMapper.toHash(DecoratingStringHashMapper.java:4
...
```

Class

```
public class AllTweets implements Serializable{
....

 public Builder getBuilder() {
     return new Builder();
    }

 public static class Builder {
        private AllTweets build;

        public Builder() {
            build = new AllTweets();
        }
        public Builder isTweet(Tweet tweet){
            build.id = tweet.getId();
            return this;
        }
        public Builder isRetweet(Retweet retweet){
            build.id = retweet.getId();
            return this;
        }
        public AllTweets build(){               
            return build;
        }
//Acessors
     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This exception doesn't have much to do with Spring. It only has to do with how Jackson automatically serializes your objects to JSON. You added a method `getBuilder()` to your class, and Jackson sees that as a rgular property of your bean that must be serialized, although it shouldn't be. So, choose another name for this method (like `builder()`), or annotate it with @JsonIgnore to make Jackson aware that this property must not be serialized.

That said, I really don't understand why this method is not `static`. You shouldn't have to create a new AllTweets object to be able to get a builder from it, to be able to build another AllTweets object. The method should thus be static, to be able to simply do

```
AllTweets result = AllTweets.getBuilder().isTweet(foo).isShare(bar).build();
```

And making it static will also solve the initial problem, because the `getBuilder()` method won't be considered as a bean property anymore by Jackson. See [Google Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) for an example implementation of this pattern: note that the method is static, and is named `builder()`.

Comment: There's no reason to have this method at all?? You access the builder doing: new AllTweets.Builder().<blah>.build().. ??

Comment: It's not absolutely required, but having a factory method is a nice thing to have.

Comment: Like a belt is nice to have when you are wearing suspenders? I don't see it, but... teho..